# Polynomial as sum of two or more reducible polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

As we know every polynomial in $z[x]$ can be expressed as sum of two irreducible polynomials. What about reducibility? Can every polynomial in $z[x]$ be expressed as sum of two or more reducible polynomials in $z[x]$?

Comment: How about $P(x)=P(x)(1-x)+P(x)x$?

Comment: @lulu nice answer, just a small note: your idea works except when $P(x)=1$.

Comment: @AnuragA  Oh, good point.  I am assuming that $\deg P(x)>0$.

Comment: To handle the case where $P(x)$ is a constant in the same spirt as my earlier expression, write $P(x)=P(x)(x^2+2x+1)+P(x)(-x^2-2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any two polynomials which are relatively prime, call them $f,g$, then 
$$\exists a(x),b(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], \,\, af+bg=1.$$
Now you can express any polynomial $p(x)$ as
$$p(x)=a(x)f(x)p(x)+b(x)g(x)p(x).$$
The summands are reducible.

Comment: dear sir, you have to show the degree is same in l.h.s and r.h.s.Here in your proof the degree varies

Comment: that is the degree of two summands should be same that of P(x).

Comment: @TAWSEEFRASHID the very fact that $af+bg=1$ suggests that the degree of the polynomial $af+bg$ is $0$, so when you multiply with $p(x)$, the degree of two sides is going to be the same.

Comment: break f(x) = 3x^5 + 7x^4 +11x^3 + 19x + 13 as sum of two reducible polynomials as per your method.

Comment: @TAWSEEFRASHID if you think my method fails then give a specific reason and then I will show you how it can be done. Otherwise follow the method I have illustrated and you will see why it works. In fact, lulu's hint works perfectly for your given polynomial and it corroborates with my idea as well.

Comment: Dear friend,i just want to write above polynomial as sum of two reducible polynomials of degree 5 by using the above mentioned method.if u please show it that will be your kindness.thank u